# How does this implementation of semaphore work?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, conditional-statements

Merry Xmas!

I'm reading the [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/). There is an implementation of semaphores in C in the book that I don't completely understand. See below for code. There is this *wakeups* variable. The author explains:

> wakeups counts the number of pending signals; that is, the number of threads that have been woken but have not yet resumed execution. The reason for wakeups is to make sure that our semaphores have Property 3, described in Section 4.3

and

> Property 3: if there are threads waiting on a semaphore when a thread executes signal, then one of the waiting threads has to be woken.

Ok, I think I understand the meaning of the property. One of the waiting threads should get the mutex and not another one (for example the signaling threads.) Correct me if I'm wrong. What I do not understand is how this property is guaranteed with this mechanism. I'd say the property is not guaranteed. It's still possible that a non-waiting process gets the mutex. What am I missing?

```
typedef struct {
  int value, wakeups;
  Mutex *mutex;
  Cond *cond;
} Semaphore;

// SEMAPHORE

Semaphore *make_semaphore (int value)
{
  Semaphore *semaphore = check_malloc (sizeof(Semaphore));
  semaphore->value = value;
  semaphore->wakeups = 0;
  semaphore->mutex = make_mutex ();
  semaphore->cond = make_cond ();
  return semaphore;
}

void sem_wait (Semaphore *semaphore)
{
  mutex_lock (semaphore->mutex);
  semaphore->value--;

  if (semaphore->value < 0) {
    do {
      cond_wait (semaphore->cond, semaphore->mutex);
    } while (semaphore->wakeups < 1);
    semaphore->wakeups--;
  }
  mutex_unlock (semaphore->mutex);
}

void sem_signal (Semaphore *semaphore)
{
  mutex_lock (semaphore->mutex);
  semaphore->value++;

  if (semaphore->value <= 0) {
    semaphore->wakeups++;
    cond_signal (semaphore->cond);
  }
  mutex_unlock (semaphore->mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `wakeups` member is not intended to protect the mutex from being acquired by something other than a waiting thread - it's intended to prevent too many threads from being released from the `sem_wait()` function.

The `pthread_cond_signal()` function call that `cond_signal()` wraps has the following statements [in its documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) (emphasis added):

> The `pthread_cond_signal()` function shall unblock **at least one** of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable `cond` (if any threads are blocked on `cond`).

And:

> On a multi-processor, it may be impossible for an implementation of `pthread_cond_signal()` to avoid the unblocking of more than one thread blocked on a condition variable.

So as an example, it's possible that when 3 threads are waiting on the condition, that two (or all three) might be released when the `cond_signal()` call is made.  The `wakeups` counter ensures that only the appropriate number of threads actually make it out of the `sem_wait()` function. The other ones will remain in the `do`/`while` loop and wait on the condition again.

Answer (score 0):

What this property means is that signaling thread should release CPU in behalf of one of waiting threads, if there are any.
pthread_cond_signal() guarantees exactly this and for the same reason.

> The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if any threads are blocked on cond).

Comment: Ok, and how does wakeups helps here? How does wakeups helps to guarantee this property?

Comment: This property is guaranteed by cond_signal(), some waiting thread will be resumed. this->wakeups just helps to count how many of them can actually continue execution. One can't rely on this->value because it can be negative, so there is need for separate variable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fine with this explanation. I understand what phtread_cond_signal does, but as far as I understand the author, that doens't guarantee the property. What about the second sentence in the first quote? "The reason for wakeups is to make sure that our semaphores have Property 3, described in Section 4.3" Doesn't the author explicitly say here that wakeups guarantee the property?